# Handle onResume in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit, android-lifecycle

I have a fragment where I post request to server. This type of action should be in **onResume()** method, but I don't want to post request to server every time when I put app on background. Is exist any solution?

> request which I want to post

```
FactoryAPI.getContacts().getContacts(user.getToken()).enqueue(new Callback<ContactsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ContactsResponse> call, Response<ContactsResponse> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    contactList = response.body().getContactsList();
                    sortList();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    setRecyclerView();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ContactsResponse> call, Throwable t) {}
        });
```

Comment: Well that depends on..when you really want to send a request. You could use a boolean and if the request is sent already then don't let it be sent again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Fragment class, create a data member of type `boolean` like,

```
private boolean isResponseSend;
```

In your `onResume()` method,

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(!isResponseSend)
        {
                isResponseSend = true;
                //your code
                FactoryAPI.getContacts().getContacts(user.getToken()).enqueue(new Callback<ContactsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ContactsResponse> call, Response<ContactsResponse> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    contactList = response.body().getContactsList();
                    sortList();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    setRecyclerView();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ContactsResponse> call, Throwable t) {}
        });


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating
you can post the request on
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.content.Context)

Answer (score 1):

Use some variable like flag, and initialise it in the onCreate. and based on the flag, you can handle the request.